# Как можно получить последовательность бит с помощью mt19937, встроенного в Numpy?

Tags: python, случайные-числа, numpy

Как можно получить в python последовательность бит из mt19937? Была идея использовать для этого сей код:

```py
import random as rd
p=[]
k=int(1.1*10**8)
for i in range(k):
  p.append(rd.getrandbits(1))
#print(p)

s=''
for i in p:
  s+=str(i)
a=p.count(0)
b=p.count(1)
f = open('sec.txt', 'w')
f.write(s)
f.close()
print(a,b)
```

но проблема состоит в том, что в документации к питоньему random не сказано,что используется именно mt19937. Поэтому стал смотреть в сторону numpy, но не смог разобраться с использованием встроенного в него mt19937 для получения бит. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: [Примеры](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/random/bit_generators/mt19937.html) не помогли?

Comment: @MaxU нет,из примеров я не понял ,как получить двоичную последовательность